# How to call a javascript function from a <c:if block

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to call a javascript function when flow enters into `<c:if>` block.

For example, I have below code:

```
<c:if test="${!empty errorMessage && !(fn:contains(errorMessage, 'generic'))}">
    <span> errorError occured<br />
    </span>
</c:if>
```

I need to invoke a JS function only when this `<c:if>` is true.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the `<script>` tag within the `<c:if>` block, something like this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty errorMessage && !(fn:contains(errorMessage, 'generic'))}">
    <span>
        errorError occured<br />
    </span>
    <script>
        alert("Calling my function ...");
        myFunction(); // this is a call to your function which must be defined in the <head> section or another JS file.
    </script>
</c:if>
```

Hope this helps.